# failing in Restore DataBase?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express

Restore failed for Server 'WIN-4TNI5VVBQ0P\SQLEXPRESS'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=9.00.2047.00&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Restore+Server&LinkId=20476

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Directory lookup for the file "D:\Orail Solution\Pharmacy_New_Work\PharmaDB.mdf" failed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.). (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=9.00.2047.00&LinkId=20476

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

this is the error that appears to me when i Restore a data base in a SQL Express edition 2005

Answer (score 5):

The error you're seeing is indicating that it can't find the directory path where the database will be restored.  It is looking to place the .mdf database file in `D:\Orail Solution\Pharmacy_New_Work`.

You need to make sure that this path exists and there is adequate permission for the restore to write to the path.

If you're not familiar with this path and/or you're not providing a destination path when you run the restore, then this path is probably the path where the database existed when the backup was created.  If necessary, you can change this destination as part of the restore.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.supportsages.com/blog/2010/02/mssql-two-common-issues-while-restoring-a-backup-and-its-solutions/ i hope it helps